# How to vertically center a table on the page?

Tags: tables

I read the documentation but there is no table parameter for center position. Only htbpH.

This is a problem because some of my tables are randomly at the top of the page, and others in the center. It makes reading them annoying.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! On a page of its own?

Comment: float pages (p) are vertically centred by default

Comment: You might be able to do it with flowfram, but you would have to know how big it is (will be) in the preamble.

Comment: You could use `\newpage\vfil\begin{table}...\end{table}\vfil\newpage`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As David Carlisle said, the (p) parameter centers the page.

Comment: Please make your answer "valid" by providing an example code. Btw it is `p` or `[p]`, not `(p)`.

Comment: But I'm the author and it answers my question.

Comment: @CodySmith (-1) Note that answers on Stack Exchange are not for the asker only, it is for everyone, even unregistered users and anonymous users. How will you think if you are another user and you goes to this question by a search engine, and you get almost zero information from the answer? (If I did't have a sufficient time with floats, I would not understand your answer at all.) An example code doesn't take much time, please add an example code in this answer and all of your questions.